# Getting 500 Server Error after Login in laravel 7

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel-7

I have downloaded my Laravel project from hosting server. Staging server correctly loaded and work. In my local, Login and Register page was fully loaded. But I got 500 server error every time after login with my credentials. And why I need to generate

> php artisan key:generate

whenever I restart the server otherwise it show me 500 server error. I can't find any solution for the last days. It makes me headaches. Sorry for my English.

In my project root folder, I have

public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my Login controller,

```
public function userLogin(Request $request)
    {
        // login when add to cart or wishlist
        $action = $request->input('action');
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $type = $request->input('type');
        $redirect = $request->input('redirect');

        $rules = [
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
        $messages = [
            'email.required'    => __('Email is required field'),
            'email.email'       => __('Invalid email'),
            'password.required' => __('Password is required field'),
        ];
        if (ReCaptchaEngine::isEnable() and setting_item("user_enable_login_recaptcha")) {
            $codeCapcha = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');
            if (!$codeCapcha or !ReCaptchaEngine::verify($codeCapcha)) {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Please verify the captcha')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors
                ], 200);
            }
        }
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error'    => true,
                'messages' => $validator->errors(),
                'redirect' => false
            ], 200);
        } else {
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $password = $request->input('password');
            $request->session()->put('user_email', $email);
            //session('user_email',$email);
            $request->session()->put('user_password', $password);
            session('user_password', $password);
            $tempUser = User::where('email', $email)->first();
            $url = strip_tags($request->input('redirect')) ? strip_tags($request->input('redirect')) : url('');
            if (empty($tempUser)) {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Username or password incorrect')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors,
                    'redirect' => false
                ], 200);
            }

            if ($tempUser->status == 'blocked') {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Your account has been blocked')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors,
                    'redirect' => false
                ], 200);
            }

            // $temp = strtolower($tempUser->roles[0]->name);
            // if ($temp == "administrator") {
            //     $checkUser = Hash::check($password, $tempUser->password);

            //     if ($checkUser) {
            //         Auth::attempt([
            //             'email'    => $email,
            //             'password' => $password
            //         ], false);




            //         $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;

            //         if ($remember) {

            //             $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
            //             Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('uplyrn_email_login', $email, $lifetime));
            //             //$response_cooki->withCookie(cookie('save_email_login',Auth::user()->email , $lifetime));
            //         } else {
            //             Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('uplyrn_email_login'));
            //         }
            //         Auth::login($tempUser, $remember);
            //         if (!empty($request->input('id'))) {
            //             if ($this->handleActionLogin($action, $id, $type)) {
            //                 if (!empty($type)) {
            //                     $key = 'isWishList';
            //                     $value = "true";
            //                     $request->session()->put($key, $value);
            //                 }
            //                 BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {
            //                     Cart::add($item->course, 1);
            //                 });
            //                 return response()->json([
            //                     'error'    => false,
            //                     'messages' => false,
            //                     'redirect' => $redirect
            //                 ], 200);
            //             }
            //         }

            //         BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {
            //             Cart::add($item->course, 1);
            //         });
            //         return response()->json(
            //             [
            //                 'error'    => false,
            //                 'messages' => false,
            //                 'redirect' => '/admin'
            //             ]
            //         );
            //     } else {
            //         $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Username or password incorrect')]);
            //         return response()->json([
            //             'error'    => true,
            //             'messages' => $errors,
            //             'redirect' => false
            //         ], 200);
            //     }
            // }
            $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;

            if (Auth::attempt([
                'email'    => $email,
                'password' => $password
            ], $remember)) {
                $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;
                Auth::login($tempUser, $remember);
                Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
                if (in_array(Auth::user()->status, ['blocked'])) {
                    Auth::logout();
                    $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Your account has been blocked')]);
                    return response()->json([
                        'error'    => true,
                        'messages' => $errors,
                        'redirect' => false
                    ], 200);
                }

                $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;

                if ($remember) {

                    $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
                    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('uplyrn_email_login', $email, $lifetime));
                    //$response_cooki->withCookie(cookie('save_email_login',Auth::user()->email , $lifetime));
                } else {
                    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('uplyrn_email_login'));
                }
                Auth::login($tempUser, $remember);
                // $url = strip_tags($request->input('redirect'));
                // $url = url('');

                if (isset(Auth::user()->roles) && !empty(Auth::user()->roles)) {
                    if (isset(Auth::user()->roles[0])) {
                        switch (strtolower(Auth::user()->roles[0]->name)) {
                            case 'administrator':
                            case 'admin':
                                //$url .= '/admin';
                                Auth::logout();
                                $request->input('redirect') ? $url : $url .= '/show2Fa';
                                break;
                            case 'lecturer':
                                $request->input('redirect') ? $url : $url .= '/user/profile ';
                                break;
                            case 'student':
                            case 'customer':
                                $request->input('redirect') ? $url : $url .= '/all-courses';
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($request->input('id'))) {
                    if ($this->handleActionLogin($action, $id, $type)) {
                        if (!empty($type)) {

                            $key = 'isWishList';
                            $value = "true";
                            $request->session()->put($key, $value);
                        }
                        BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {

                            Cart::add($item->course, 1);
                        });
                        return response()->json([
                            'error'    => false,
                            'messages' => false,
                            'redirect' => $redirect,
                        ], 200);
                    }
                }

                BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {

                    Cart::add($item->course, 1);
                });

                // var_dump(auth()->user());
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => false,
                    'messages' => false,
                    'redirect' => $url ? e($url) : url(app_get_locale(false, '/'))
                ], 200);
            } else {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Username or password incorrect')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors,
                    'redirect' => false
                ], 200);
            }
        }
    }
```

After login from controller I returned Json data to my ajax success method. In my seccess method, I redirect route to (127.0.0.1:8000/) that is from **data.redirect**. After that I got 500 server error.

```
$.ajax({
      url: bookingCore.routes.login,
      data: {
        email: form.find('input[name=email]').val(),
        password: form.find('input[name=password]').val(),
        remember: form.find('input[name=remember]').is(':checked') ? 1 : '',
        'g-recaptcha-response': form.find('[name=g-recaptcha-response]').val(),
        redirect: form.find('input[name=redirect]').val(),
        action: form.find('input[name=action]').val(),
        id: form.find('input[name=id]').val(),
        type: form.find('input[name=type]').val(),
      },
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function() {
        form.find('.error').hide();
        form.find('.icon-loading').css('display', 'inline-block');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        form.find('.icon-loading').hide();
        if (data.error === true) {
          if (data.messages !== undefined) {
            for (var item in data.messages) {
              var msg = data.messages[item];
              console.log(item);
              form
                .find('.error-' + item)
                .show()
                .text(msg[0]);
            }
          }
          if (data.messages.message_error !== undefined) {
            $('.form-right-question p').addClass('form-right-question-change');
            form
              .find('.message-error')
              .show()
              .html(
                '<div class="message-login">' +
                  data.messages.message_error[0] +
                  '</div>'
              );
          }
        }
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.redirect !== undefined && data.redirect) {
          window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
      },
    });
```

Is there anything I miss, thanks before, sorry for bad English.

Comment: If you have to call `php artisan key:generate` every time you start the server there is something wrong with your server in some way. Can you post the log files (Server, Laravel, PHP)? Even an HTTP 500 might have an error in the server log to help find the problem.

Comment: Yes, I found that it is a codebase issues. But that code really work in server not in my localhost. ```if(Auth::id())``` that code works in server not in my local. So I have to edit the code manually in my local with ```if(!empty(Auth::id()))``` instead of  ```if(Auth::id())```. Please what makes the problem?

Comment: Why not check if URL contains localhost then do code a, else code b. I do have that running for me, works like a charm. No need to change code then

Comment: Because those codes are written by other developer. We have to maintain. But the problem is why not work in my local even it is the same code?

Comment: Again, looking in the logfiles will help. You can post the messages here or google them directly.